# How to run scripts as user (not as root) in lightdm?

Tags: scripts, lightdm

I want to run some scripts before login every time my PC is started. I add the scripts in as greeter-setup-script in lightdm.conf. However, all the scripts are running as root! I want to use normal user account (e.g. myUserName) to run these script. Is it possible to do so? I try to include "su - myUserName" in the scripts, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su [username] -c [command to run]
```

Replace the bracket instances above with:

```
username                 = your user name
script/command to run    = The name of the script you're want to run as you.
```

Comment: @Starry, please consider marking the accepted answer or added the accepted answer and marking that as the answer so that others having a similar question will see a resolution with an accepted answer.  Also some contributors who are trying to help the users scan for questions without accepted answers.  This question will remain flagged as a question needing an answer until it's marked as answered.  Your update to advise us that your problem is solved is an attributed contribution, marking it as answered would be anther big step/contribution in the same direction.

Comment: Sure! I have just marked it as answered! Thank you James! I also tried to +1 it, but due to my current low reputation I cannot do that...